# Como ler e exibir dados no Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, edittext

Como ler os dados digitados pelo usuário em um EditText e exibir em uma nova activity no Android Studio?  Já tentei de algumas maneiras, mas ao exibi-lo na outra activity só aparece "false".

Comment: Poste a maneira que tentou. Sem seu código, dificilmente alguém conseguirá te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

**Dica:**

> Aprenda **Java** ou **Kotlin** antes de começar, será muito bom para o seu
>   conhecimento, pois o Android gira em torno destas linguagens de
>   programação orientada a objetos.

**Como Fazer:**

```
private EditText mEditText;
mEditText = findViewById(R.id.NOME_DA_ID);

public void onClickButton(){
    Button mBtn= findViewById(R.id.NOME_DA_ID);
    mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("TAG", mEditText.getText());
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, OutraActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

**Observação:**

**EditText:** Classe que tem todo o contexto de onde você está digitando o valor, criar uma variável privada e criar get e set da mesma para inserir e pegar valores;

**Bundle:** Passará a informação que deseja para uma outra Activity, através de uma "TAG";

**Intent:** Irá alterar de Activity, juntamente com o Bundle para passar as informações a outra Activity;